# I want to call rest api in my function app azure using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-functions

I am very new to C# and Azure. I want to call my rest api (I already have a REST API) from an Azure Function app.

I am able to call my API without Azure Function and below is the code. I have to do same in my function app .

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("**my url was here**");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer **token**";

httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Please help me write the code for this. The requirement is call REST API in the Azure Function app and consume the returned JSON data.

The actual problem is I want to make Azure Function app which call/consume my REST API and read the JSON data.

Can I use above code in function app in http trigger? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `Azure http trigger function`, and then put your code directly into it, you can refer to the following code:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net;

namespace FunctionRestApi
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URL");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer **token**";

            httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
             SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                log.LogInformation(result);
            }

            return new OkObjectResult("ok");
        }
    }
}
```

I did a test, and it worked well.

Comment: what about if I want to add query parameter like "url/id" . I have to make ID as  optional parameter.

Comment: Just add your parameters to the back of URL, like this: `<your-url>?id=<your-id>`, then get this parameter in your code, like this: `string id= req.Query["id"]`;

Comment: Hi @FrankGong Its not working. when I pass id 10 in <your id> it is still giving complte detail from id 1

Comment: Do you want to add parameters when requesting `Http Trigger Function` or when requesting `Rest api`?

Comment: rest api. example <url>/cat .... then other api is <url>/dog . so this url is same only the end part is changing.

Comment: if (data_type ="cat") { <url>?data_type="cat" should be excuted                                         elseif <...>